# Prove $ \frac{\sqrt{2}}{2} + \frac{\sqrt{3}}{4} + \frac{\sqrt{4}}{6} + \cdots + \frac{\sqrt{n+1}}{2n} > \frac{\sqrt{n}}{2} $ by induction

Tags: discrete-mathematics, inequality, summation, induction, radicals

> Prove by induction that for all $n > 0$,
>
> $$
> \frac{\sqrt{2}}{2} + \frac{\sqrt{3}}{4} + \frac{\sqrt{4}}{6} + \cdots
> + \frac{\sqrt{n+1}}{2n} > \frac{\sqrt{n}}{2}
> $$

I have done the basis step, where $n = 1$ and showed that L.H.S is > R.H.S

For inductive step, I assume $n = k$ & L.H.S > R.H.S is true.

However, I am stuck at showing how for $k + 1$, it is also true for L.H.S > R.H.S

Any help will be much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: If you could share your work for $n=k+1$ case maybe we can direct you to your source of confusion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(Someone please check for error ... I'm not confident if I got this correct)

Since for the base case $n=1$: $\dfrac{\sqrt2}2>\dfrac{\sqrt 1}2$, you just have to prove that $\dfrac{\sqrt{n+1}}{2n}\geq\dfrac{\sqrt{n}}2-\dfrac{\sqrt{n-1}}2$ for $n>1$ since, if $a>b$ then $a+c>b+d$ for $c\geq d$.

\begin{align*}
\frac{\sqrt{n+1}}{2n}&\geq\frac{\sqrt n-\sqrt{n-1}}2\\ \\
\frac{\sqrt{n+1}}{n}&\geq\sqrt n-\sqrt{n-1}\\ \\
\frac{\sqrt{n+1}}{\sqrt n-\sqrt{n-1}}&\geq n\\ \\
\sqrt{n+1}(\sqrt n+\sqrt{n-1})&\geq n\\ \\
\sqrt{n^2+n}+\sqrt{n^2-1}&\geq n\\\square
\end{align*}

(note that $\sqrt{n^2+n}>n$ since $\sqrt{n^2}=n$ for $n\geq1$)

Comment: Sounds about right to me.. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

By cross-multiplying, it can easily be seen that
$$
\begin{align}
\frac{\sqrt{k+1}}{2k}
&\gt\frac1{\sqrt{k+1}+\sqrt{k\,}}\\[6pt]
&=\sqrt{k+1}-\sqrt{k\,}
\end{align}
$$
Summing gives
$$
\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{\sqrt{k+1}}{2k}
\gt\sqrt{n+1}-1
$$
This is not the inequality given, but for $n\ge2$, $\sqrt{n+1}-1\gt\frac{\sqrt{n}}2$.